Advice on migrating from LLVM legacy FunctionPassManager to new PassManager
I currently have a compiler where I use the legacy FunctionPassManager. My code for this is essentially identical to the Kaleidoscope implementation here: https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/BuildingAJIT2.html.
Here is the relevant snippet from the tutorial:
class KaleidoscopeJIT {
private:
  ExecutionSession ES;
  RTDyldObjectLinkingLayer ObjectLayer;
  IRCompileLayer CompileLayer;
  IRTransformLayer TransformLayer;

  DataLayout DL;
  MangleAndInterner Mangle;
  ThreadSafeContext Ctx;

public:

  KaleidoscopeJIT(JITTargetMachineBuilder JTMB, DataLayout DL)
      : ObjectLayer(ES,
                    []() { return std::make_unique<SectionMemoryManager>(); }),
        CompileLayer(ES, ObjectLayer, ConcurrentIRCompiler(std::move(JTMB))),
        TransformLayer(ES, CompileLayer, optimizeModule),
        DL(std::move(DL)), Mangle(ES, this->DL),
        Ctx(std::make_unique<LLVMContext>()) {
    ES.getMainJITDylib().addGenerator(
        cantFail(DynamicLibrarySearchGenerator::GetForCurrentProcess(DL.getGlobalPrefix())));
  }

static Expected<ThreadSafeModule>
optimizeModule(ThreadSafeModule M, const MaterializationResponsibility &R) {
  // Create a function pass manager.
  auto FPM = std::make_unique<legacy::FunctionPassManager>(M.get());

  // Add some optimizations.
  FPM->add(createInstructionCombiningPass());
  FPM->add(createReassociatePass());
  FPM->add(createGVNPass());
  FPM->add(createCFGSimplificationPass());
  FPM->doInitialization();

  // Run the optimizations over all functions in the module being added to
  // the JIT.
  for (auto &F : *M)
    FPM->run(F);

  return M;
}

I'm struggling to understand how to adapt this to use the new PassManager, since I will also have to change how the TransformLayer is used TransformLayer(ES, CompileLayer, optimizeModule), since optimizeModule must return a ThreadSafeModule and I'm not sure how to do that with the new PassManager.
I have read the docs on using the new pass manager and I have been looking at how other people have done the migration on their Githubs but I can't find an example that is similar to mine.
I would really appreciate any pointers, or if someone has resources to share. Thanks in advance.
